# How to assign value to a prop NOT inside onChange in ReacJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, assign, prop

I have a multi-step Form components and I need to update a state that been sent from a different component.
in the first component I have states:

```
export class BookForm extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            service: '',
            price: ''
```

Now I have this method:

```
handleChange = input => event => {
        this.setState({
            [input]: event.target.value
        });
    }
```

I pass this method with the other props to a diffrent component and whenever "onChange" happends I call it with the name of the prop inside like this:

```
onChange={this.props.handleChange("service")}
```

That way the onChange event is assiging to the prop.

I have a problem because I have a value that is coming back from an API and I need to assign it to a prop.
I'm having trouble to assign the value inside the prop **from the second component without 'onChange'.**
Is there a method I can pass to the component that I can use? The function I showed here works with onChange.

Thanks a lot!

Edit:
This is the part from the child component:

```
<select 
            class="form-drp-btn"
            onChange={this.props.handleChange("service")}
            onInput={(e) => {this.setPrice(e)}}
            >
```

the steps are like this:
with "onChange" I get the service that been chosen. with "onInput" I get the price that coming back from the API and belong to the certain service.
Now, I want to assign this value to the "price" state that came from the father component.

Comment: check out formik for complex forms.

Comment: Could you please show us the part of the child component that tries to update the parent prop?

Comment: I added the part from the child component. Hope it helps!